# Why can't I access iframe function from parent

Tags: javascript

In example https://codepen.io/grimen/pen/naENeK I have added

```
  <script>function test(){alert("test")};test()</script>
```

and wanted to access it from parent with

```
  window.frames['blob-src-test'].contentWindow.test();
```

but it doesn't work:

```
  Uncaught TypeError: window.frames.blob-src-test.contentWindow.test is not a function
```

in

```
  var template = [
    '<h1>',
    variables.title,
    '</h1>',
    '<img width="80%" src="',
    variables.image,
    '">',
    '<script>function test(){alert("test")};test()</script>'
  ].join('');

  window.frames['blob-src-test'].contentWindow.test();
```

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the parent? You can't access anything between different domains.

Comment: @Barmar source is Blob so I think yes.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I think each blob might be considered its own domain.

Comment: Also note that all codepens themselves run in iframes at the origin `https://cdpn.io`

Comment: It works if you wait for the frame to be loaded: `blob_iframe.addEventListener('load', (e) => e.target.contentWindow.test());` https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/OJvKdoz

Comment: @blex ah yes !!!